# Adding unique identifiers to ReactJS Webapp

Tags: reactjs, testing

A large ReactJS code base is built, the testing team has requested us to add unique identifiers to each component to automate the testing process. 
We tried approaches like parsing through each file and adding id, using react-uid etc. none proved to be feasible. 
If anyone has similar experience, is there a feasible way to do it? The codebase is large.

By Component I mean any JSX that react renders.

The parse all files is not feasible as the codebase is large, and there are some issues like

- Not having a proper library to find all the JSX. (I tried using Acornify)
- This technique won't work when I reuse the components(like buttons)
- The ID must be static, if I add a new component, it should not change the IDs of already existing.

Comment: What is a "component" here that needs to be identified uniquely?  Can you explain in detail how the things you tried are not feasible for you?

Comment: I have edited the question. Let me know if u need further details